# How to utilize django generic view?

Tags: python, html, django, web

For example, I want a page, which will let user add data for different categories of goods.

Like:

Model: Category is foreign key of item

```
Category1(detail url): 
    Item 1(detail url):
        Date(textbox), Amount(textbox), Price(textbox)
    Item 2:
        ...
Category2:
...
Save button, add more button, etc...
```

Since this is an example, I what those thing all display in a page.

I don't mind hard writing them with normal functions, but I wonder if I can utilize the views, since if they are so heavily introduced and developed, they might be powerful. So why not utilize it?

Can anyone tell me tricks about how to use them or we shouldn't use them if we want more functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's generic views cover a lot of common use cases. For example:

- CreateView - a view for creating an instance of a model
- UpdateView - a view for updating an existing instance of a model
- DeleteView - a view for deleting an existing instance of a model
- DetailView - a view for displaying the details of an exsting instance of a model
- ListView - a view for displaying a list of instances of a model

There are more around if you need them, and they cover the majority of views you are likely to need. You can also extend them to meet your needs quite easily. As a general rule of thumb, they make such a huge difference to how quickly you can get something built that I would recommend using them by default, and only switching over to writing your own views when absolutely necessary. If you haven't yet learned them, I think doing so will be a very good investment of your time - you will make up the time spent very quickly. For a lot of view types, it's just a case of specifying the model, setting up the URLs and the template, and you're done.

If you need to pass through additional data, then you can extend the generic view in question and override the `get_context_data()` method. If the same needs to be applied to several different generic views, you can create a mixin that includes that method and include it in that generic view.

For views that include forms, like the CreateView and UpdateView, as Drewness said, you can pass through a ModelForm instance to tell it what form to use, and that form can itself be overriden, so you still have a lot of control over what the form will do. For instance, you might define the following form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    exclude = ['date_created']
```

And the following view

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class CategoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    form_class = CategoryForm
```

The Django tutorial [covers generic views pretty well](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#amend-views).

Comment: I read those articles, but maybe I still need a hint. Like in the example, we can use a list view to list all the Categories, it seems we also can use form view to fill the data, etc. What I mean is how can we combine these views together? Inheritance?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine these views together?"

Comment: If you're referring to the views for creating and editing data, then what you can do is specify a form for that data. You can create a form for the view and pass it to the generic view, and it will use that form. That form can be a ModelForm, which is derived directly from the model

Comment: I am a little confused now. But I think what I have in mind is, ListView is going to get a list of objects, and pass to the template, then, render a HttpResponse object. While CreateView will get one object, and render a HttpResponse object. I want every object of ListView have a FormView, while I think these two process is incompatible, how will django handle these, these two views have two routines, right? Maybe mixin is going to solve this, I though mixin was a class between baseview and generic view.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. I want to list all categories, for each category, I want to list all the items of it, and each item have a form to edit it.

Comment: What you want is doable. Just use a listview to show the categories and have each one include a link. Then, that link points to another listview that shows all the items in that category. Finally, make the link in each item point to an UpdateView for that item.

Comment: Don't forget, you can use whatever template you like for the listviews, so you have the freedom to render the data as you wish. Generic views just pass that data through.

Comment: By link, you mean url link or else? I hope I can display them all in a page, without clicking. Just like an inline of the admin app. If I do most of the work in template, I think there's not much different from using TemplateView.

Comment: Not really as a TemplateView doesn't accept the data that's passed through. All you need to do is use a foreach loop to loop through the objects in the template and include a link to the object in question. If you set up a `get_absolute_url()` method for the model to point to the URL you want, then you can easily render that URL in the template

Comment: I actually wrote [a tutorial on building a blog with Django that makes heavy use of generic views](http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2013/12/28/django-blog-tutorial-the-next-generation-part-1/), and you might find it handy if you're having trouble with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django's [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) with a [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview).

Then all of the fields in your model will be available in your form and in your form view. You should also look at [mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/). Mixins allow you to use combinations of class-based views.

Finally, if you want to use more than one form (model) in a view you can use a [`FormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).